# Python - using a non-integer number instead of an integer

Tags: python-3.x, signal-processing

I am trying to write some code in python for data segmentation, here is my code 
it consists of two functions. I used python 3.5

```
def windowz(data, size):
    start = 0
    while start < len(data):
        yield start, start + size
        start += (size / 2)

def segment_dap(x_train,y_train,window_size):
    segments = np.zeros(((len(x_train)//(window_size//2))-1,window_size,9))
    labels = np.zeros(((len(y_train)//(window_size//2))-1))
    i_segment = 0
    i_label = 0
    for (start,end) in windowz(x_train,window_size):
        if(len(x_train[start:end]) == window_size):
            m = stats.mode(y_train[start:end])
            segments[i_segment] = x_train[start:end]
            labels[i_label] = m[0]
            i_label+=1
            i_segment+=1
    return segments, labels

input_width = 23
if dataset =="dap":
    print ("dap seg")
    input_width = 25
    print ("segmenting signal...")
    train_x, train_y = segment_dap(x_train,y_train,input_width)
    test_x, test_y = segment_dap(x_test,y_test,input_width)
    print ("signal segmented.")
```

but this code gives me the following warning

```
    Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\Deep-Learning-for-Human-Activity-Recognition-master\ModelCreation\RNN\FFLSTM\fflstm.py", line 37
    if(len(x_train[start:end]) == window_size):
VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\Deep-Learning-for-Human-Activity-Recognition-master\ModelCreation\RNN\FFLSTM\fflstm.py", line 38
    m = stats.mode(y_train[start:end])
VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\Deep-Learning-for-Human-Activity-Recognition-master\ModelCreation\RNN\FFLSTM\fflstm.py", line 39
    segments[i_segment] = x_train[start:end]
VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(size / 2)` in:

```
def windowz(data, size):
    start = 0
    while start < len(data):
        yield start, start + size
        start += (size / 2)
```

Will give you a float. You can force it be an integer with:

```
(size // 2)
```

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem. Just click on the check mark (✓) next to the answer. This will toggle it from grayed-out to filled-in.